# How can i add random texts to Unity Textmesh?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am a total beginner with unity and have very little to no knowledge in programming.

for an unity game scene i would need to pull random texts that should be displayed in a textmesh canvas.

could somebody help me with a beginner friendly how-to do this?

i found this posting that discribes some code how to do it...

edited (this is the correct link):
https://answers.unity.com/questions/756090/how-can-i-change-textmesh-to-a-random-text-snippet.html

But how can this code be implemented.

I would create a new cs-script file. What should i include besides of the code mentioned? And how can i connect that to the textmesh object in the canvas of the game scene?

Hope you can help me and sorry for asking such stupid/basic things!

All the best,
Mark

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 1):

I found the best way to do this would be to have a string array:

> `string[] words = { "word A", "word B" }; etc...`

then you can call this line of code which will have your random word

> `string randomWord = words[Random.Range(0, words.Length)];`

ok, how can this be used?

here is a way:

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;


public class something : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string[] words = { "Word A", "Word B" };
    public TMP_Text text;

    private void Start()
    {
        // log whatever comes out of the RandomWord string.
        string wordToDisplay = RandomWord();

        text.text = wordToDislpay;
    }

    // when you see a string function,
    // it will return a string that
    // you can use anywhere!
    private string RandomWord()
    {
        // grab a random string from the words array
        string randomWord = words[Random.Range(0, randomWord.Length)];

        // return it (this will be the string that the script will use)
        return randomWord;
    }
}
```

if you are using the normal UI text and not TEXT MESH PRO, then instead of using `TMPro;`, use `using UnityEngine.UI;`, And `TMP_Text` would just be `Text`. the string array can be changed in the inspector, which is the best bit!

You should be able to do anything you want with this.

Good luck with unity!

Comment: Incase you didn't know, text mesh pro is just a better version of unity's original ui text simply for it's crispier text, rather than the blurry text that unity's stock one has.

Comment: hey, thanks for answering! yes, it‘s cleat that textmesh is just advanced regular text. i will try that code and will come back with feedback. thanks a lot for helping!!

Comment: tried it, this the error code i get: Assets/Journey/Scripts/Others/RandomText1.cs(24,51): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'randomWord'

Comment: this is the script used

Answer (score 1):

i was able to solve it using this code.

big thanks to you!!!!

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;


public class RandomText1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string[] words = { "XA", "XB", "XC" };
    public TMP_Text text;

    private void Start()
    {
        // log whatever comes out of the RandomWord string.
        string wordToDisplay = RandomWord();

        text.text = wordToDisplay;
    }

    // when you see a string function,
    // it will return a string that
    // you can use anywhere!
    private string RandomWord()
    {
        // grab a random string from the words array
        string randomWord = words[Random.Range(0, words.Length)];

        // return it (this will be the string that the script will use)
        return randomWord;
    }

}
```